# Hacer cálculos en una Tabla JS/TS

Tags: javascript, typescript

Cordial saludo, estoy trabajando con una tabla que tiene 4 columnas, la cual tiene un campo input en la columna 3 al que se le ingresara un valor y en base a se valor se debe calcular que porcentaje es con respecto a una formula y agregar ese valor al td en la columna correspondiente. ¿Como puedo agregar el porcentaje respectivo del PMM a cada fila?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para el calculo del porcentaje es tener en cuanta el 100% es un millón.

Esto es lo que he intentado para calcular el total la cantidad PPM

```
private calcularPorcentajeMezcla() {
    let total = 0;
    $('#data-table-receta-1 tbody').find('.ppm-1').each(function () {
        total += parseFloat($(this).val().toString());
    })

    console.log(total);
}

<table id="data-table-receta-1" class="Highlight">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th data-field="id">Producto</th>
        <th data-field="tipo">Tipo</th>
        <th data-field="cant">Cantidad PPM</th>
        <th data-field="acc">Porcentaje</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select class="select2 browser-default" @*asp-for="@Model.RolId" name="Estado" id="terminal-estado" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.Roles))*@>
                <option value="" selected disabled>Seleccionar clase</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>Base</td>
        <td><input type="text" style="width:70%" class="ppm-1" name="Nombre"></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select class="select2 browser-default" @*asp-for="@Model.RolId" name="Estado" id="terminal-estado" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.Roles))*@>
                <option value="" selected disabled>Seleccionar clase</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>Base</td>
        <td><input type="text" style="width:70%" class="ppm-1" name="Nombre"></td>
        <td class="porcent"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para calcular el porcentaje respectivo en cada fila podes aprovechar mientras recorres los `.ppm-1` en la tabla para buscar el `td.procent` en la misma fila.

#### Ejemplo:

```js
function calcularPorcentajeMezcla() {
  let total = 0;
  // Buscamos todos
  $('#data-table-receta-1 tbody').find('.ppm-1').each(function() {
    // Obtenemos los elementos en la fila
    let $input = $(this),
     $tr = $input.closest('tr'),
     $tdPorc = $tr.find('td.porcent'),
     value = parseFloat($input.val());
    
    if (isNaN(value)) value = 0;
     
    // Calculamos el % ("Regla de 3 simple")
    $tdPorc.text((value * 100 / 1000000) + '%');
    
    //
    total += value;
  })
  console.log(total);
}

// Suscribimos una funcion al evento "input" en los inputs de la tabla
$('#data-table-receta-1').on('input', '.ppm-1', calcularPorcentajeMezcla);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="data-table-receta-1" class="Highlight">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th data-field="id">Producto</th>
      <th data-field="tipo">Tipo</th>
      <th data-field="cant">Cantidad PPM</th>
      <th data-field="acc">Porcentaje</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <select class="select2 browser-default" @*asp-for="@Model.RolId" name="Estado" id="terminal-estado" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.Roles))*@">
          <option value=" " selected disabled>Seleccionar clase</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>Base</td>
      <td><input type="text " style="width:70% " class="ppm-1 " name="Nombre "></td>
      <td class="porcent"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <select class="select2 browser-default " @*asp-for="@Model.RolId " name="Estado " id="terminal-estado " asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.Roles))*@">
          <option value="" selected disabled>Seleccionar clase</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>Base</td>
      <td><input type="text" style="width:70%" class="ppm-1" name="Nombre"></td>
      <td class="porcent"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

---

Referencias:

- [jQuery.closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)
- [isNaN()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN)

---

Observaciones:

- Te faltaban cerrar comillas dobles (`"`) en algunos atributos
- Ta faltaba la clase `porcent` en un `td`

Comment: Muchas gracias, y que pena molestar, pero de casualidad no habrá forma de hacer esta parte

`$('#data-table-receta-1 tbody').find('.ppm-1').each(function() {`

Solo con JS?

Comment: @JohanMeneses, si te referias a hacerla sin `jQuery`, la respuesta es si, por supuesto que se puede. Te recomiendo leer [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll). Si necesitas mas ayuda, no dudes en crear una nueva pregunta. Saludos!